# Why gradient color pick tool behaves strangely many times?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This really irritates me many times, I guess especially in gradients that I haven't created.

In first image, you can see the gradient pick tool is selected on right side, and on left side, a solid color is selected because I have selected a pointer of gradient (see right). This is what I need, so I can double click the solid color (the foreground background tool on very left highlighted) and pick color I need from the popup.

In 2nd image, everything is same, just a different gradient and on the very left, you see gradient is selected instead of solid color. I can doube click it but once I select the color from the color popup, it turns the gradient to solid color. This is what I don't need.

3rd picture is of the *double click popup* I mean. **I like this popup because I can't find it anywhere else in my illustrator in case of gradients like these.** Here I can easily choose an random color, in this case the grey colors, unlike swatches with limited colors.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit (To show that both cases have gradient tool selected):

[image]

**Why is this strange behavior?**

Comment: Use the **Color *Panel***, not the color picker.

Comment: Let me guess its a alpha mask not a color

Comment: @joojaa  Scott do you wanna see open file for the same?

Comment: Don't need to see anything... it's the "double-click to open the picker" that is the poor part of the workflow.. use the Color Panel.

Comment: @Scott by Color Panel you mean this: ? https://helpx.adobe.com/in/illustrator/using/selecting-colors/_jcr_content/main-pars/image_1.img.png/cl_06.png

If yes, I

Comment: ...I'm not able to pick grey shades from it unlike the "double click" color pick window I mentioned, where you can easily pick any shade of any color. That's the problem.

Comment: Vikas, you can pick greys from the color panel.. you can pick **any** color from the color panel. You simply aren't familiar with the panel. Truth of the matter is you do **not** *ever* need the color *picker* in Illustrator and the picker is *not* as integrated into the application as it is in other Adobe apps, such as Photoshop. The **Panel** is the *intended* method of color choosing.

Comment: @Scott thanks for letting me know this. But I'm still not sure which "window" you mean by Panel. Could you please share a screenshot? That way I could ask maybe another question why I *can't* pick grey color shades.

Comment: Vikas... Window > Color -- yes that screenshot. How many Panels are titled "Color"? I don't' know why you can't pick a grey. Set the Panel to greyscale.. you get a K slider.. set the percentage to what grey % you want.

Comment: @Scott I think what I'm calling "window" is actually Panel. That's why confusion. Anyway let me check.

Comment: @Scott okay, yes, it's the same panel that I shared in link. I'll ask a separate question to describe the problems with it, that I do face. Would like you to see.

Comment: I think the bulk of your issue here, @Vikas is the double-clicking color stops for the gradient.. don't do that.. click a stop once, and use the Color panel. Just because you *can* do something In Illustrator doesn't always mean the devs really intended that to be the proper workflow and devoted time to making it a fluid feature. The Color *Picker* is really just there so people don't complain about it *not* being there.

Answer (score -1):

The difference in behavior has to do with the fact that in your first example you have the Gradient Tool at work. In the other instances you simply have an object selected.

With the Gradient Tool at work. Then yes, the stroke/fill selector (what you called the foreground/ background tool which is more a Photoshop terminology) works as you like to change the color of *whatever individual color stop of the gradient* you have selected.

I find this quite  unusual and not very intuitive- in fact I never even knew the Fill/ Stroke selector would work this way when using the Gradient Tool. Typically, I will just select the color stop I want to modify (in the Gradient Panel or on the Gradient Tool) to change that individual color from the Swatches or the Color Panel (as @Scott suggests).

In your second and third example you have an object selected- then the Fill/Stroke selector works exactly as expected. It will change your Gradient fill into a solid color fill if you double click it and choose a color from the pop up color picker.

So, you must be working on the gradient itself ***with the Gradient Tool*** to have the Fill/Stroke Selector work as you wish.

Comment: if you see my edit, both cases have gradient tool selected.

Comment: To clarify @ Vikas- When you have the Gradient Annotator showing on screen (View>Show/Hide Gradient annotator) and a color stop chosen (in either the Annotator or the Gradient Panel) you get this different behavior-  you get a single color in the Fill box which you can change as you have been by double clicking the fill box. Then go up to View>Hide Gradient Annotator and the Fill Box changes to show the entire Gradient. In this state when you change the color it changes the entire Fill to what ever your chosen color is- that is the different behavior that you are asking about in your question.

Comment: yes I agree, but why is it happening that Gradient annotator is not showing in one case and in one case it is showing? Even when I've selected the same tools and color point. Just the objects are different.

Comment: @Vikas For the most part you need to change how you think when working In Illustrator. Rather than defaulting to "Why isn't the app working". You *should* default to "What am **I** doing differently which is causing different behavior?" - for example.... *"Just the objects are different."* is a **very** telling statement.. the gradient annotator only works on *some* object, not all. And it only works if you are working on a **fill**. So.. if the annotator is not appearing.. you need to ask.. "What's different about these objects" rather than thinking the app is "broke" or "failing".

Comment: @Scott I realized this only after Kyle's last comment, that I could ask it this way.

Comment: So I have the half of answer :D